# Java 32 bit -- can't allocate more than -Xmx512m? 8 GB, 64 bit Windows 7

Tags: java, memory-management, pentaho

I'm using the ETL program Pentaho for data integration. I've run into memory problems, but I get a fatal error everytime I set "-Xmx512m" to anything higher (1024+).

I have Java 32 bit on my computer --- would installing Java 64 bit maybe solve this issue? (I need IT to install programs). I thought the max GB for 32 bit was at least 1G.

Again, my computer has 8 GB of physical memory ... I don't have much open right now -- what could be the problem? What can I do to fix this?

Comment: And what's the fatal error? Any reason you're using a 32-bit JVM on a 64-bit machine to start with?

Comment: It doesn't say. Well, I guess it's "Could not create the Java Virtual Machine". My hunch is that, for Windows in particular, there is some hard-coded limit for 32 bit Java, and in my case, it's (somehow) even less than 1300m. Any reason I'm using 32 bit? Well, I didn't initially install it here ... so I'm not sure. Maybe it was a security concern, or ... who knows. Due to security procedures I can't run .exe files directly --- it's quite the nuissance, you might imagine.

Comment: Well I'm sure I've used significantly more than 512MB on a 32-bit JVM in the past - but it would be much better if you would just get a 64-bit JVM installed on the machine.

Answer (score 0):

The limit for anything 32bit is max ~3GB but that is for code running native. Java runs inside a virtual machine. The max that all of Java could use would be ~3GB, but there are other parts than just your code running to keep Java up and running, not to mention other 32bit code on your machine.

Also, the specific thing you could be calling could be limited to a registry of no more than 2^10 (1024) megabyte entries.

So, switching to 64 bit might help with your problem, but there is no guarantee and something meant to run on your system native would likely use a smaller footprint for the kind of code you're running.

Comment: "Also, the specific thing you could be calling could be limited to a registry of no more than 2^10 (1024) megabyte entries." What do you mean by this? What exactly would be limiting the ETL job inside the Pentaho application? Also, most computer in this office do not even have Java installed, so I doubt there's a lot of other background stuff going on (other than keeping the VM running as you said)

Comment: Java as a platform uses memory and other resources to run, the code doesn't execute directly on the CPU it is abstracted through running code, not assembly on machines (which is how it works cross platform).

And I am not sure which methods are getting called inside Pantaho that could be limited. Some data types have size limitations on their arrays or lists.

Comment: I'm still confused. On the forums Pentaho experts frequently suggest to up the "xmx" paramter to 1 gig, or 2 gigs. So it seems the application would support it perfectly fine. I also just upgraded to 64 bit java. So far I'm getting the same error, but I'm not sure if I need to change 'which java' to use manually somewhere. Is the limitation my computer's physical memory at 8 GB? What exactly is the limitation here? I can extend the computer's physical memory, if you think that is the issue.

Comment: Let me ammend that --- I had to change JAVA_HOME environmental variable ... NOW it appears to work with java 64 bit ... man that took some time to figure out.